# помогите найти момент завершения работы javascript

Tags: javascript

подключаю модуль jQuery File Upload на к одному из проектов, но понадобилось изменить способ отображения информации после его работы. 
Суть в чем, пользователь к примеру добавляет  несколько фоток в загрузку, плагин их грузит, и когда все фото загрузились нужно обновить страницу.

в этом файле http://zastavna.rayon.cv.ua/js/jquery.fileupload-ui.js есть функция которая отвечает за отображение прогресбара загрузки файлов, так вот, никак не могу понять как его переделать, чтоб когда прогрес бар дошел до 100%, страница перезагрузилась.

пример работы самого скрипта http://zastavna.rayon.cv.ua/index.php?folder_user=fdg

насколько понял за процесс вывода (или формирования) прогресбара отвечает этот код

```
// Callback for global upload progress events:
            progressall: function (e, data) {
                if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
                    return false;
                }
                var $this = $(this),
                    progress = Math.floor(data.loaded / data.total * 100),
                    globalProgressNode = $this.find('.fileupload-progress'),
                    extendedProgressNode = globalProgressNode
                        .find('.progress-extended');
                if (extendedProgressNode.length) {
                    extendedProgressNode.html(
                        ($this.data('blueimp-fileupload') || $this.data('fileupload'))
                            ._renderExtendedProgress(data)
                    );
                }
                globalProgressNode
                    .find('.progress')
                    .attr('aria-valuenow', progress)
                    .children().first().css(
                        'width',
                        progress + '%'
                    );
            },
```

но как правильно там добавить перезагрузку страницы по завершению, ума не приложу

Comment: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5263/186999)

Comment: дополнил вопрос

Comment: `progressall` - это настройки чего `jquery.fileupload-ui.js`?

Comment: не знаю (( нашел еще такую функцию _onProgress: function (e, data) { в ней фигурирует эта настройка, в файле http://zastavna.rayon.cv.ua/js/jquery.fileupload.js

я просто в javascript очень плохо разбераюсь, на уровне нуба, в основном на PHP програмирую

Answer (score 0):

в onProgress можно отслеживать прогресс загрузки.

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Extended-progress-information